# Waitlisted Indian train ticket: will I be refunded if I don't get a confirmed seat?

Tags: trains, tickets, india, seating, refunds

I've purchased a ticket on [Cleartrip](http://www.cleartrip.com) from Gorakhpur to Delhi. I'm on a wait list on 33. If I do not get a confirmed seat, will I be refunded?

Answer (score 10):

I believe the limited answer to this comes [from their website](http://www.cleartrip.com/terms/policy_train.html):

> **Fully waitlisted e–tickets will be cancelled by Railways after chart
>   preparation and the refund shall be automatically credited to
>   Cleartrip account**. After chart preparation, refunds for partially
>   waitlisted/confirmed/RAC e–ticket will be processed on a receipt of
>   mail from customer at etickets@irctc.co.in. It would then be processed
>   offline and refund sanctioned by Railways would be credited back to
>   Cleartrip. To claim your refunds for offline cancellations, please
>   contact Cleartrip customer support by writing an email with your PNR
>   and trip details to customersupport@cleartrip.com

Answer (score 5):

I know it is a little late to respond, but I am replying in the hopes that this may help others.

I bought a ticket from Cleartrip on a waitlisted train, since their site said they will issue a full refund if you are not able to get on the train. When the train was overbooked and I was not able to get on, they did issue a refund, but with about $5 deducted. When I contacted them why they did not issue a "full refund", their reply was that they charge a processing fee just for reserving through their site, and that is not considered part of a "full refund."

In short, you will pay whether you get on the train or not.